# Connecting slider to separate graphics view in OS X Cocoa using Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a custom class containing a slider and plotting code and these are connected to a view in an OS X storyboard. Unfortunately, the slider is in the plotting area and I can not place it in a different part of the window since the slider is not recognized outside of the plotting class. (This seemed to easy to do in Objective C using nibs). Can someone suggest a way of doing this? The slider code is:

```
    @IBAction func freqValue(sender: NSSliderCell) {
        freq = Float(sender.doubleValue)
        display()
    }
```

The custom plotting class is SineCurveView.

Thanks!

Comment: Again, I answered my own question. Dragging from the slider to the @IBAction didn't work, instead I needed to drag to the Custom View in the storyboard. Now it works fine. (I am just getting used to the somewhat different procedures from what I was used to some 10 to 15 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Can you make an outlet for it in the appropriate view and set it up programmatically there? I might not have a full understanding of the setup however, im on the iOS side.